# Efficient computation of Euclidean distance between cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I have an `a`-by-`b` cell array, `C`. In each element, there is a float array.

I now want to create a new symmetric matrix `M`. Each element `(i, j)` in `M` is to be set to the sum of the Euclidean distances of all the respective float arrays in `C`.

For example, to find `M(i,j)`, I would take the set of `b` float arrays in `C` along row `i`, and the set of `b` float arrays in `C` along row `j`, find the Euclidean distance between each array across the two sets, and then sum up the `b x b` values. `C{i,j}` is a column vector. All columns are the same length.

Below is my "brute force" implementation of this:

```
for i=1:a
    for j=1:a
        dist_sum = 0;
        for k=1:b
            for l=1:b
                dist = sqrt(sum((C{i, k} - C{j, l}) .^ 2));
                dist_sum = dist_sum + dist;
            end
        end
        M(j, i) = dist_sum;
        M(i, j) = dist_sum;
    end
end
```

My question: Is there a more efficient way of doing this using matrix operations, without having to explicitly compute each Euclidean distance in turn?

Comment: What is exactly the contents of `C{i,j}`? A row vector? With the same length for all `i` and `j`?

Comment: `C{i,j}` is a column vector. All columns are the same length.

Comment: I would be waaay easier if you had a 3D array C(i,j,k), where  `k` is each vector component. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Can you convert your cell array to a matrix using `cell2mat`? That should make it easier to use functions like `pdist`.

Comment: If all your elements in your cell-array C are of the same type, you should be using a normal array/matrix. This will improve your memory consumption and, as @2cents says, will be easier to use that array/matrix in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a 3D array, instead of a 2D cell array of equal-size column vectors.

If you have a cell array: first convert into a 3D array (`D` in my code); then it's easy to compute distances with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); and finally apply [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
D = permute(C, [3 1 2]);
D = reshape(cat(2, D{:}), [], size(C,1), size(C,2)); %// 3D array
dist = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, D, permute(D, [1 4 5 2 3])).^2)); %// distances
M = squeeze(sum(sum(dist, 3), 5)); %// sum of distances
```

Example: with

```
>> C = {[1; 2], [30; 40], [0; 1]; [5; 7] [19; 17] [4; 5]}; %// a is 2, b is 3
```

the result of both your code and mine is

```
M =
  196.8391  182.8791
  182.8791   77.3002
```

Comment: Wait, "if you really need a cell array, first convert into a 3D matrix"? I'm confused.

Comment: @2cents I meant: the OP should use a 3D matrix (as we all agree in the comments). If he/she has a cell array, it can be done, but the first step is to convert to a 3D matrix. I'll make that clearer in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure about converting it to a 3D array. If I use cell2mat on `C`, then it gives me a 2-dimensional array of size `(a x b) x f`, where `f` is the length of the float array, rather than a 3D matrix.

Comment: @Karnivaurus Do the conversion as in my code -- first two lines: `D` is the 3D array

Answer (score 0):

Before Calculating Euclidean Distance:

Can convert the cell array to matrix by using cell2mat... then u can use following methods..

Method 1:

```
G  = rand(1, 72);
G2 = rand(1, 72);
D  = sqrt(sum((G - G2) .^ 2));
```

Method 2:

```
V = G - G2;
D = sqrt(V * V');
```

Method 3:

```
D = norm(G - G2);
```

Method 4:

```
D = pdist2(G,G2);
```

Comment: Do any of these approaches address cell arrays?

Comment: can convert the cell array to matrix by using cell2mat... then u can use these methods..

Comment: I would add that to the begining of your post to help address the OPs question more directly.

Comment: Careful with the `'` in method 2! I don't think the complex conjugate transpose is meant here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the matrix elements to a vector using `(:)` and then using [`distance2curve.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34869-distance2curve) function file from Matlab File Exchange to find the minimum/Euclidean distance between the two arrays.

Let's say the two cell arrays are `A` and `B` with matrices containing the row and column indices for each cell array denoted as 'indA' and 'indB', where each row in 'indA' and 'indB' contains the row element and column elements of 'A' and 'B', respectively. Now use the above function as:

```
[M, distance, t] = distance2curve(indA(:, :), indB(:, :))
```

The output variable `M` should contain the minimum/Euclidean distance between the two arrays that you are looking for.